# Make that target="_blank" open always in the same window (not parent window)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, mobile, browser

I have a form with a target = _blank set up, which works as intended, but I am looking to make the submit form opens on the same window don't matter how munch submit I do. Does it make sense?, example:

**Current behavior is:**

- "Parent window" has the form
- When submit the first time a second window is opened, let called "Window Child 1" (until here is fine)
- When I submit the form a second time another child window is loaded (I don't want this)

**Behavior I need:**

- When I submit the form the second time I need to get the content on the same window that the first submit used "Window Child 1". Doing this I look to overwrite the result of the first submit with the second one on the same window.

I did this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5jmnk1rm/

```
<form action="/" method="post" id="form1" target="_blank">   
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />        
</form>
```

*Note: I should not use window.open (due other codes, etc...)*

**Update**

I've changed the target="_blank" to target="customName" and it opens different windows in Chrome mobile (iOS). I am starting to think it is a bug on the browser

Answer (score 8):

All you need to do is replace _blank with a specific name.

```
<form action="/" method="post" id="form1" target="foo">   
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />        
</form>
```

However you are in for some other complications like, the fact that some browser will open a new tab, instead of a window.

**Additional Info**

If you need to force opening in a new window regardless of how the user's browser is configured, you will have no choice but to use window.open. By setting the height and width options, you can force a window to open, not a tab.

Comment: I did what you said @Jeffrey A. Gochin here in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5jmnk1rm/1/ but it does not work. Also I don't care it open in a new tab, actually that is what I am looking for in Chrome iOS (to avoid open many tabs and re-use only one tab)

Comment: Does work outside of JSFiddle? JSFiddle may be causing the problem in this case.

Comment: Try this plnkr.  After you click the first time a new tab opens, then subsequent clinks in the new tab or the original page still target the new tab.  http://embed.plnkr.co/ogDgvuQgrjDmKhluTkU8/preview

Comment: your example works fine in desktop but it open multiple tabs in Chrome mobile

Comment: what do you mean @Jeffrey A. Gochin ? putting a height/with where? (just in case you meant of a pop-up window "window.open" I am trying to do a simple target action)

Comment: I forgot about your requirement not to use window.open.  What is the reason for that requirement?

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide a name for the window. `_blank` is a special case that will always create a new window. If you specify `target="my-form"`, or some other name, it will reuse the child window.

Comment: I did what you said @pmccloghrylaing here in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5jmnk1rm/1/ but it does not work

Comment: Try it with an HTML file, rather than in JSFiddle.

Comment: yes I tried and it opens a multiple tabs in Chrome mobile where I want to make it work